# CASE w/ DATEADD range to SUM column multiple times for future earnings estimate

Tags: mysql, sum, case, dateadd

EDIT: The original post follows, but its a bit long and wordy. This edit presents a simplified question.

I'm trying to `SUM` 1 column multiple times; from what I've found, my options are either `CASE` or `(SELECT)`. I am trying to SUM based on a date range and I can't figure out if `CASE` allows that.

```
 table.number  |  table.date  
   2        2014/12/18
   2        2014/12/19
   3        2015/01/11
   3        2015/01/12
   7        2015/02/04
   7        2015/02/05
```

As separate queries, it would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(number) as alpha FROM table WHERE date >= 2014/12/01 AND date<= DATE_ADD (2014/12/01, INTERVAL 4 WEEKS)
SELECT SUM(number) as beta FROM table WHERE date >= 2014/12/29 AND date<= DATE_ADD (2014/12/01, INTERVAL 4 WEEKS)
SELECT SUM(number) as gamma FROM table WHERE date >= 2014/01/19 AND date<= DATE_ADD (2014/12/01, INTERVAL 4 WEEKS)
```

Looking for result set

```
alpha   |   beta   | gamma
  2          6         14
```

ORIGINAL:
I'm trying to return `SUM` of payments that will be due within my budgeting time frame (4 weeks) for the current budgeting period and 2 future periods. Some students pay every 4 weeks, others every 12. Here are the relevant fields in my tables:

```
client.name |   client.ppid |  client.last_payment
john            |   1       |   12/01/14
jack            |   2       |   11/26/14
jane            |   3       |    10/27/14       



pay_profile.id  | pay_profile.price | pay_profile.interval  (in weeks)
        1                   140                     4
        2                   399                     4
        3                   1                       12

pay_history.name    |   pay_history.date  | pay_history.amount 
john                |       12/02/14      |        140
jerry               |   more historical   |       data


budget.period_start |
        12/01/14
```

I think the most efficient way of doing this is:

1.)SUM all students who pay every 4 weeks as `base_pay`

2.)SUM all students who pay every 12 weeks and whose `DATEADD(client.last_payment, INTERVAL pay_profile.interval WEEKS)` is `>= budget.period_start` and `<= DATEADD(budget.period_start, INTERVAL 28 DAYS)` as `accounts_receivable`

3.) As the above step will miss people who've already paid in this budgeting period (as this updates their last_payment dating, putting them out of the range specified in #2), I'll also need to SUM pay_history.date for the range above as well. `paid_in_full`

4.) repeat step 2 above, adjusting the range and column name for future periods (i.e. `accounts_receivable_2`

5.) use php to SUM `base_pay`, `accounts_receivable`, and `pay_history`, repeating the process for future periods.

I'm guessing the easiest way would be to use CASE, which I've not done before. Here was my best guess, which fails due to a sytax error. I assuming I can use `DATE_ADD` in the `WHEN` statement.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    DATE_ADD(client.last_payment, INTERVAL pay_profile.interval WEEK) >= budget.period_start 
    AND 
    DATE_ADD(client.last_payment, INTERVAL pay_profile.interval WEEK) <=                                                           
    DATE_ADD(budget.period_start,INTERVAL 28 DAY) THEN SUM(pay_profile.price) as base_pay
FROM client
LEFT OUTER JOIN pay_profile ON client.ppid = pay_profile.ppid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN budget ON client.active = 1
WHERE
client.active = 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: You lost me. Consider providing proper DDLs and a desired result set.

Comment: Does the edit clear it up?

Comment: For me? No, it doesn't.